# showing overlay help in android app

Tags: java, android

I have an app where the action bar and notification bar is hidden when user opens the app. I have seen some apps where some overlay help is shown with the image of a hand and up,down arrows and text below which says:
"Tap to view action bar. Tap again to go full screen"

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use full screen for your app unless you **really** knows it's the only way. Full screen is annoying for user as you hides clock, nottifications etc.

As for help you may want to use ShowCaseView library: https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView